# Sequence contains no matching element error when returning class Type of Interface using IsAssignableFrom

Tags: c#, selenium, ui-automation

This is a follow up question to another post I created around implementing a UI test solution that could toggle which classes to execute code from based on interfaces. The whole goal was to re use test code on versions of apps that are identical (Web vs WPF).

The code compiles fine, but after the test is ran it bombs out on the GetPageModelType method call. Below is my implementation pretty much identical to the linked post, with a few minor adjustments to abstract some of the page object creation on a TestClassBase

[UI Test that can determine which classes to execute code from at runtime using interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71228903/ui-test-that-can-determine-which-classes-to-execute-code-from-at-runtime-using-i/71326877?noredirect=1#comment126506992_71326877)

**Interface and corresponding Page Object classes**

```
public interface ILogin
{

    void Login(string username, string password);

}

public class WebLogin : ILogin
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public WebLogin(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Web Success!");
    }
}

public class WPFLogin : ILogin
{
    private readonly WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;

    public WPFLogin(WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WPF Success!");
    }
}
```

**Page Object factory classes**

```
public interface IPageModelFactory
{
    ILogin CreateLogin();
}

public class WebPageModelFactory : IPageModelFactory
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public WebPageModelFactory(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public ILogin CreateLogin()
    {
        return new WebLogin(driver);
    }
}

public class WPFPageModelFactory : IPageModelFactory
{
    private readonly WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;

    public WPFPageModelFactory(WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public ILogin CreateLogin()
    {
        return new WPFLogin(session);
    }

}

public class PageModelFactory
{

    private readonly object client;

    public PageModelFactory(object client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    // Create Page Objects
    public ILogin CreateLoginPage()
    {
        var pageModelType = GetPageModelType<ILogin>();
        var constructor = pageModelType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { client.GetType() });
        return (ILogin)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { client });
    }

    private Type GetPageModelType<TPageModelInterface>()
    {
        return client.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Single(type => type.IsClass && typeof(TPageModelInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    }

}
```

**TestClassBase - base class for tests, simplifies test scripts**

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClassBase
{

    // WinAppDriver variables
    private static string WinAppDriverExe = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Application Driver\\WinAppDriver.exe";
    private string WindowsApplicationDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723";

    // Sessions
    public WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;
    public IWebDriver driver;

    // Declare Page Objects
    public ILogin login = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        if (GlobalData.targetHost.Equals("WPF"))
        {
            // Capabilities
            AppiumOptions appCapabilities = new AppiumOptions();
            appCapabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("app", GetExeFile());
            appCapabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appWorkingDir", GetWorkingDirectory());
            
            // Create Session
            session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appCapabilities, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
            session.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            // Pass session to page objects
            PageModelFactory wpfPages = new PageModelFactory(session);
            login = wpfPages.CreateLoginPage();

        } else if (GlobalData.targetHost.Equals("Web"))
        {

        }
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        // Clean up code...
    }
    }
```

**LoginTests**

```
public class LoginTests : TestClassBase
{

    [Test]
    public void Login()
    {
        // Login
        login.Login("", "");

    }

}
```

Whats not pictured above is my GlobalData.cs class which just contains a bunch of hardcoded variables that are used in the tests. I have the targetHost variable set to "WPF" while testing this against the WPF host. The StartUp code does launch the app as expected, it fails when we call GetPageModelType on PageModelFactory.CreateLoginPage();

Comment: Does the client come from the same assembly/DLL that contains the concrete page model classes?

Comment: Oh! Now I realize what the problem is. Pass the assembly that contains the page models in as a separate parameter to the page model factory constructor. That wasn't something I could foresee in your previous question. Sorry about that. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to see this in my answer on your original question. The assembly in which the "client" resides and the assembly in which the page models reside are different. That means the PageModelFactory will need a second constructor parameter to know which assembly to search when initializing new page models:

```
public class PageModelFactory
{

    private readonly object client;

    private Assembly Assembly => GetType().Assembly;

    public PageModelFactory(object client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    // Create Page Objects
    public ILogin CreateLoginPage()
    {
        var pageModelTypes = GetPageModelTypes<ILogin>();
        var constructorSignature = new Type[] { client.GetType() };

        foreach (var type in pageModelTypes)
        {
            var constructor = type.GetConstructor(constructorSignature);

            if (constructor != null)
                return (ILogin)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { client });
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"No class found implementing ILogin with a constructor that accepts {client.GetType().FullName} as an argument in assembly {Assembly.Name}");
    }

    private IEnumerable<Type> GetPageModelTypes<TPageModelInterface>()
    {
        return Assembly.GetTypes()
                       .Where(type => type.IsClass
                                   && typeof(TPageModelInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey a different error this time! Now its 'Sequence contains more than one matching element' :)

Comment: @Tree55Topz: that is probably happening when both the WPF and web page models exist in the same assembly. Consider splitting those into their own assemblies or projects, because they do have different dependencies.

Comment: Another solution is to find all classes that implement that interface, and then choose the one class that supports the constructor that takes an instance of the `client` as a parameter.

Comment: Would it just be the WebPageModelFactory and WPFPageModelFactory that would need their own assemblies? Never worked with multiple projects/assemblies in a solution before

Comment: The page models themselves would need their own assemblies/projects. The page model factory should be general purpose, and wouldn't matter which project it is in.

Comment: hmm so like WebLogin and WPFLogin? Would we need an assembly for each page object thats made or is it more like one assembly for Web and one for WPF.. then each page object that inherits from the interface would go under the WPF or Web assembly. Im assuming the page object interfaces like ILogin would be general purpose as well

Comment: So how could I reference WPFLogin and WebLogin when I create the page from the model factory classes? I cant add them as a reference to my primary project because I would then have circular references

Comment: Or would I need to add another layer for the WebPageModelFactory and WPFPageModelFactory? Right now what I did is create two new assemblies in the solution for a total of 3. I have UITest which is my primary, WebPageObjects and WPFPageObjects. I left the interfaces on UITest and added the WebLogin and WPFLogin classes to their new assemblies. This meant I needed to add UITest as a reference, but now I dont see how I am able to call any of these classes from UITest

Comment: I cant seem to break this up in a way without running into circular dependancies

Comment: The problem area is `pageModelAssembly.GetTypes().Single(...)`. It sounds like you need to use `.Where(...)` and then loop over the returned Type's to decide which one has a constructor that accepts `client` as an argument.

Comment: @Tree55Topz: I updated my answer. To avoid circular dependencies, it looks like all page models and page model interfaces should be in the same Visual Studio project. The assumption is the page model factory exists in that same assembly.

Comment: Thanks! So I moved everything into one project/assembly. Assembly.Name wasnt resolving to anything and was throwing a syntax error so I changed that to Assembly.GetName(). It compiled and ran without error, but was printing out Web Success. doesnt look like it executed the code from WPFLogin

Comment: So If i comment out the code for WebPageModelFactory and WebLogin, it ends up using WPFLogin. So in this case, it seems like either work but it still is not resolving the desired.. Ill try adding some more code to pick based off GlobalData.targetHost

Comment: So actually this seems to work fine if in the TestClassBase when I go to initialize the page objects instead of instantiating it as PageModelFactory, I use WPFPageModelFactory. Do I even need the PageModelFactory class?

Comment: Greg, so this works great if I just do like the comment above. It actually seems like we do not need PageModelFactory class at all since we are doing the instantiation from the TestClassBase individually for Web and WPF. Ran through some test cases, and this is working great so far. I cant thank you enough for your time and help in solving this